# Why I can't increment the parameter of the simple constexpr function?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++14, constexpr

Visual Studio 2015 Update 3.

I read the *Programming. Principles and Practice Using C++* (second edition) by *Bjarne Stroustrup*. I learn the `constexpr` functions...

It works:

```
constexpr int get_value(int n) {
    return n + 1;
}
```

But I can't compile this (instead of the first variant):

```
constexpr int get_value(int n) {
    return ++n;
}
```

I get the error:

> constexpr function return is non-constant

The `n` is the *local* variable for the `get_value` function. I.e. `n` variable changing doesn't influence to external code.

Why the second variant of the `get_value` function is wrong?

Comment: Try a proper compiler.

Comment: I tesedt in `codeblock` with `g++  5.3.1` and woked.

Comment: @k-five, Hm... Maybe my problem is specific for IDE which I use...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second one is not allowed in C++11 `constexpr`. The standard even had a very similar example (N3337 [dcl.constexpr]/3):

```
constexpr int prev(int x)
{ return --x; } // error: use of decrement
```

N3337 [expr.const]/2 explicitly bans "increment or decrement operations" in constant expressions.

C++14 extended `constexpr` relaxes those requirements, but MSVC doesn't implement that.

Comment: Hm... why it was banned? What danger in it?

Comment: @AndreyBushman : No danger, just purity of specification: _no mutation allowed_. The limitation disappears with C++14 because it allows mutation in general, not just because increment and decrement operations are no longer singled out.

Answer (score 2):

The second one is legal under C++14 but it doesn't compile because Visual Studio 2015 has only partial support for `constexpr` functions. It only has support for single-return `constexpr` functions and other limitations (like yours), which where in effect in C++11.

See [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/02/11/compiler-improvements-in-vs-2015-update-2/) article (in the `constexpr` paragraph). Visual Studio "15" will bring improvements to `constexpr` functions. You'll have to wait a bit :)